# Allow number between 0 and 100 in python

Tags: python

So far I have this piece of coding. I'm trying to only allow numbers between 0 and 100.

and also input an error handler (Messagebox)

```
#This function will let the user at to the list
def add():
        try:
            value = int(ent1.get())
            mark.set(value)
            exammarks.append(value)
            lst1.insert(len(exammarks),value)
        except:
```

Anybody help?

Comment: No excepts without specific errors please

Comment: ent1 is the entry box i'm using.

Comment: Unsure what to put under the except condition.

Comment: Maybe ValueError. Try running this code: http://repl.it/SVQ

Comment: @Aidan Your title and what to write under except is not related. You might want to read up on the statement. And basic python in general.

Comment: To everyone suggesting list answers. Won't that iterate over all values? Or will it be optimized thanks to `range` somehow?

Comment: In Python 3, `range` would create a class that has an efficient test using `__contains__`. In Python 2.x, `range()` would create a list; even `xrange()` does not implement `__contains__` and would therefore have to iterate through all values. I'd say even in Py3 it is not the proper way to test unless e.g. you also have a `step`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the built-in `assert` keyword?

```
def add():
    try:
        value = int(ent1.get())
        assert 0 <= value <= 100
        # continue processing
    except AssertionError:
        # handle exception as you wish
        pass
```

Comment: It now only allows values between 0 and 100! :D Just need to get the Error message to display now.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can write it pretty much like a regular math expression:

```
foo = 50
if 0 <= foo <= 100:
    print "yup"
```

Or, with a try-except (this can be done in several different ways):

```
foo = 101
try:
    if 0 <= foo <= 100:
        print "yup"
    else:
        raise ValueError, 'The number must be in the range 0-100'
except ValueError, e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_range = range(0,100)
>>> 10 in my_range
True
>>> 101 in my_range
False
>>>
```

Comment: `0 <= value <= 100` would be the proper way to do this, at least in Python 2.x.

Comment: That's awesome, haven't think about it.